# how to append IQueryable within a loop

Tags: c#, entity-framework, webforms

I have a simple foreach loop that goes through the productID's I have stored in a user's basket and looks up the product's details from the database.

As you can see from my code, what I have at present will return the very last item on screen - as the variable is overwritten within the loop. I'd like to be able to concat this so that I can display the product details for the items only in the basket.

I know I could do something very easy like store only ProductIDs in the repeater I use and onitemdatabound call the database there but I'd like to make just one database call if possible.

Currently I have the following (removed complex joins from example, but if this matters let me know):

```
IQueryable productsInBasket = null;
    foreach (var thisproduct in store.BasketItems)
    {
        productsInBasket = (from p in db.Products
                                 where p.Active == true && p.ProductID == thisproduct.ProductID
                                 select new
                                 {
                                     p.ProductID,
                                     p.ProductName,
                                     p.BriefDescription,
                                     p.Details,
                                     p.ProductCode,
                                     p.Barcode,
                                     p.Price
                                 });
    }

    BasketItems.DataSource = productsInBasket;
    BasketItems.DataBind();
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you *really* want something like:

```
var productIds = store.BasketItems.Select(x => x.ProductID).ToList();
var query = from p in db.Products
            where p.Active && productIds.Contains(p.ProductID)
            select new
            {
                p.ProductID,
                p.ProductName,
                p.BriefDescription,
                p.Details,
                p.ProductCode,
                p.Barcode,
                p.Price
            };
```

Comment: Hi Jon, thanks for that. It worked a treat! I would never have thought of doing the filter like that before. Handy to know :)

Answer (score 0):

In Jon's answer, which works just fine, the IQueryable will however be converted to an IEnumerable, since you call ToList() on it. This will cause the query to be executed and the answer retrieved. For your situation, this may be OK, since you want to retrieve products for a basket, and where the number of products will probably be considerably small.

I am, however, facing a similar situation, where I want to retrieve friends for a member. Friendship depends on which group two members belongs to - if they share at least one group, they are friends. I thus have to retrieve all membership for all groups for a certain member, then retrieve all members from those groups.

The ToList-approach will not be applicable in my case, since that would execute the query each time I want to handle my friends in various ways, e.g. find stuff that we can share. Retrieving all members from the database, instead of just working on the query and execute it at the last possible time, will kill performance.

Still, my first attempt at this situation was to do just this - retrieve all groups I belonged to (IQueryable), init an List result (IEnumerable), then loop over all groups and append all members to the result if they were not already in the list. Finally, since my interface enforced that an IQueryable was to be returned, I returned the list with AsIQueryable.

This was a nasty piece of code, but at least it worked. It looked something like this:

```
var result = new List<Member>();
foreach (var group in GetGroupsForMember(member))
    result.AddRange(group.GroupMembers.Where(x => x.MemberId != member.Id && !result.Contains(x.Member)).Select(groupMember => groupMember.Member));
return result.AsQueryable();
```

However, this is BAD, since I add ALL shared members to a list, then convert the list to an IQueryable just to satisfy my post condition. I will retrieve all members that are affected from the database, every time I want to do stuff with them.

Imagine a paginated list - I would then just want to pick out a certain range from this list. If this is done with an IQueryable, the query is just completed with a pagination statement. If this is done with an IEnumerable, the query has already been executed and all operations are applied to the in-memory result.

(As you may also notice, I also navigate down the entity's relations (GroupMember => Member), which increases coupling can cause all kinds of nasty situations further on. I wanted to remove this behavior as well).

So, tonight, I took another round and ended up with a much simpler approach, where I select data like this:

```
var groups = GetGroupsForMember(member);
var groupMembers = GetGroupMembersForGroups(groups);
var memberIds = groupMembers.Select(x => x.MemberId);
var members = memberService.GetMembers(memberIds);
```

The two Get methods honor the IQueryable and never convert it to a list or any other IEnumerable. The third line just performs a LINQ query ontop of the IEnumerable. The last line just takes the member IDs and retrieves all members from another service, which also works exclusively with IQueryables.

This is probably still horrible in terms of performance, but I can optimize it further later on, if needed. At least, I avoid loading unnecessary data.

Let me know if I am terribly wrong here.